# Is there a way to call on the HTML element without using tagname?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a simple question:
Is there a way to call on the HTML element without using:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0]
```

using JavaScript. For getting the body you can do:

```
document.body
```

Is there a simpler way to do this with JavaScript?

Comment: You should read [JavaScript HTML DOM Navigation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_navigation.asp) and [How to traverse the DOM in Javascript](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-traverse-the-dom-in-javascript-d6555c335b4e) to gain basic knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these can be used to get a reference to the `<html>` element:

- `document.documentElement`
- `document.querySelector('html')`
- `document.querySelectorAll('html')[0]`
- `document.getElementById('foo')`  - if `<html id="foo">` is set
- `document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0]` - if `<html class="bar">` is set
- `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]`
- `document.head.parentElement`
- `document.body.parentElement`

You can also get a reference to the root `<html>` element by navigating upwards using `parentElement` or `parentNode`:

```
var anyElement = document.getElementById('somethingOtherThanHtml');
var htmlElement = anyElement;
while( htmlElement.tagName != "HTML" ) {
    htmlElement = htmlElement.parentElement;
}
```

And `document` is also a member of `window` (in fact, `window` is the "root object" in all browser web-page scripting scenarios), so if you only have `window` you can go `window.document.documentElement` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference `document.documentElement`:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0] === document.documentElement);
```

Comment: But, is there a way without using tag name, or is this the only way? Thanks, though

Comment: `document.documentElement` does not use the tag name of "HTML" at all..? It's just like `document.body`

Answer (score 1):

You can add an ID to the HTML element and then use document.getElementById("idOfTheElement")

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `document.getElementByClassName("classname")`.

classname represents the class for that tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use queryselector:

```
document.querySelector('HTML')
```